# Preventing a control from loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do I prevent a control that is displayed in the ASPX page from loading ?

Basically, I have an ASP.NET web form with a single `ObjectDataSource` that is feeding 2 GridViews (let's call them `gvSystemA` and `gvSystemB`). That `ObjectDataSource` is getting its data from a SQL Server stored procedure.

That stored procedure extracts data from either System A or System B, depending on the value of the "System" parameter. These 2 systems are completely different so the output from that stored procedure is different as well.

So I basically want to display `gvSystemA`, or `gvSystemB`, but not both. The `ObjectDataSource` and both Gridviews are on the aspx page. How do I prevent gvSystemA or gvSystemB from loading from code-behind ?  I tried several things but it still tries to load both Gridviews:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["System"] == "sysA")
        {
            gvSystemB.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            gvSystemA.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

And I get the following error (as the DataFields from gvSystemA are different from gvSystemB):

> A field or property with the name 'TELEPHONENUM' was not found on the selected data source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property not Enabled. When you set Visible=false, then it should be hidden from UI and shouldn't do Data binding.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["System"] == "sysA")
    {
        gvSystemB.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        gvSystemA.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.  Don't know why, but I never thought of using Visible as I thought that if Enabled=false didn't work, Visible wouldn't either.  But now it makes senses that Visible is related to the UI.  Thanks !